# How do I make my gas furnace throw out warmer air?

Tags: furnace, gas

I just bought a new house. It has a 2007 gas furnace. The make is a 2007 heil furnace .

I would like to know how to adjust the furnace to make it throw warmer air out of the ducts.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Furnaces are either one stage where they output a single temperature, or two stage where they output two different temperatures depending on the temperature difference they make up.  Your thermostat controls this.

The air coming out of your furnace is far hotter then your thermostat setting, but your thermostat shuts off the furnace when the ambient air temperature reaches its setting.

Your only real option you can control is how long you run the furnace for.

Answer (score 0):

As @Steven has stated the temperature is fixed based on the size of the burner, which is dictated by the design of the furnace. There are things you can do to increase the efficiency some you can do and some require a burner technician. Make sure the filter is clean, make sure the registers (outputs and returns) aren't blocked by furniture, check for leaks in the exposed duct work and seal with metal or duct tape not to be confused with the silver packing tape. Insulate any exposed ductwork that is uninsulated. If you haven't done it this year have the furnace inspected and cleaned and adjusted, also ask  if the ductwork needs cleaning.

Comment: Not duct tape, only metal tape.. Duct tape is not for ducts.